# PHPMailer via Cron job stopped working in July on Bluehost

Tags: php, cron, phpmailer, bluehost

The script was running fine by the 20th of July. It is still working, when run via URL address. But when it is run via Bluehost Cron job, it does not send out an email.

I have seen another similar thread, where recommended solution was to set the "Helo" property on your mail object. I added these two lines into the script:

```
$mail->Hostname = "bluehost.com";
$mail->Helo = $mail->Hostname;
```

But mails are still not sent. Can please someone help? I would like to have exact solution.

Thank you.

Comment: For an exact solution, we need an exact symptom. Read your error logs. It's likely to be something like differences in PHP config between PHP web and CLI SAPIs, such as include paths or permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now. The two lines of code were good enough to make it working again. I had another non related error in the script.